# Solving for $U$,$\Sigma$ and $V$ in SVD of a matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, svd, orthogonal-matrices

Knowing from theory that fro a matrix $A$ we $A = U\Sigma V^{T}$

I want to solve for $U$,$V$ and $\Sigma$.
My effort is the following but I don't if I am correct.
\begin{align*}
A &= U\Sigma V^{T} \\
U^{T}A&=  \Sigma V^{T}\\
U^{T}&= \Sigma V^{T}A^{-1}\\
U&= \Sigma^{-1}V A
\end{align*}
and

\begin{align*}
A &= U\Sigma V^{T} \\
A\Sigma^{-1}&=  UV^{T}\\
\Sigma^{-1}&= A^{-1} U V^{T}\\
\Sigma&= U^{T}A V
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
A &= U\Sigma V^{T} \\
A V  &= \Sigma  U \\
V &=\Sigma U^{T}A ^{-1}
\end{align*}

Along with $A^{T}=V\Sigma U^{T} $
\begin{align*}
A&=USV^{T}  \\
A^{T}A &= V\Sigma U^{T}U\Sigma V^{T} \\
A^{T}A &= V\Sigma^{2}V^{T} \\
A^{T}AV &= V\Sigma^{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I'd be really careful with $A^{-1}$, since the SVD decomposition exists for matrices with different dimensions. The third section is what tells em the morst information, mainly that $V$ contains the eigenvectors of $A{*} A$. If you try to simplify $A A{*}$, you'll find similar information about $U$.